# How to change tuple shape?

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, data-analysis

**what should i do so that a tuple of (1,2,3) is changes to ((1,2),3).**
I was trying to use the code

```
index_transform = [(lambda (a,b,c) : ((a,b),c)) (x) for x in index]
```

but i was getting error invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
orig_tup=(1,2,3)
##tuple slicing with square brackets
tup_of_tups=(orig_tup[0:2], orig_tup[2:3])
print(tup_of_tups)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are confusing lambda functions and list comprehension. In this case, you don't need to iterate through each element of the array. If the array does not change its shape, you should edit the lambda function in this way:

```
index=(1,2,3)
foo = lambda a: ((a[0],a[1]),a[2])
index_transform = foo(index)
print(index_transform)
```